# Heatmap with matplotlib - Unexpected image

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I am trying to visualize the Dirichlet distribution though a Heatmap but I get an unexpected image.  What is the reason for this?

My code is:

```
a = np.random.dirichlet(alpha = [0.3, 0.7], size = 1000)
plt.imshow(a, cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

The image is:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot more rows in the array `a` than you have columns.

Probably you want to show the image with an unequal aspect ratio. For that set

```
plt.imshow(a, aspect="auto")
```